# PrimaryKey, ForeignKey и их особенности

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с MySQL. Курс ознакомительный, но все же хотелось бы знать хотя бы азы.
Нашел один пример:

```
 CREATE TABLE usr (
    usr_id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    FIRST  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
       surname  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY(usr_id)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
  CREATE TABLE product (
       prod_id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      name  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      descr  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(prod_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
   CREATE TABLE invoice (
    inv_id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    usr_id  INT NOT NULL,
    prod_id  INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(inv_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (usr_id) REFERENCES usr(usr_id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES product(prod_id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
```

Суть следующая: таблица товаров, покупателей и таблица заказов. 
Вопросы:

1. Первичный ключ и внешний - это, я так понимаю, одно и тоже для
   разных таблиц: к примеру, prod_id для таблици продуктов - PK, а для
   заказов - внешний?
2. Строчка `usr_id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,` означает создание первичного ключа таблици покупаителей, ID увеличиваеться автоматом и не может быть нулевым?
3. Что делает `ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;` (что - то с кодировкой) и обязательно ли это?
4. В данном случае родительскими будут покупатели и продукти, таблица заказов - дочерняя?
5. Запись `FOREIGN KEY (usr_id) REFERENCES usr(usr_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,` показывает, что изменение записи продукт отображается в заказах, а изменение в заказе не отобразится на продукте (так было написано на сайте)? Правильно ли я понял, если убрать продукт то и заказ, связанный с ним уберется, а если, к примеру, покупатель отменил заказ, то товар остаеться в таблице товаров? И эти особенности (изменения) указываються всегда и только после внешних ключей родительских таблиц для данной дочерней при ее создании?
6. Последний вопрос состоит в связях. Я читал.что в БД есть разные связи, например, один ко многим, многие ко многим и один к одному. Как в случае с вишеупомянутым примеров созданы связи? Ведь покупатель может заказать не один товар, а два и более? Это ведь не указывается  конкретно или я чего - то не вижу? С самого начала я думал, что по сути одной записи соответствует другая. Или же именно благодаря этим пресловутым ключам и создаеться связь: один покупатель может иметь несколько товаров - один ко многим. Правильно лми я понимаю, корректно ли выражаюсь, если да.

P.S.: возможно многим вопросы покажутся профанскими, но для этого ведь и создан форум. Заранее благодарю того, у кого хватит терпения мне ответить.

Comment: SO - не форум, и создан он не для этого. Почти на все ваши вопросы краткий ответ - "нет, это не так". Если есть желание разобраться - найдите другой учебник. Желательно не по MySQL

Comment: все не так, и это все?

Comment: я не отвечал на ваш вопрос, я написал комментарий. Подождите, может кто и ответит. Но, вообще говоря, вопросы из 6 частей тут не приветствуются.

Comment: а пресловутые слова: "Не стыдись спросить - не знать еще постыднее" пропагандируемые сайтом лишь дымок, который легко развеять? Вы конечно извините но, понимаю, что может вопросы и глупые, но отнюдь не не в тему, и ответы из розряда "ты кретин и как вообще посмел о таком спросить" не следует писать здесь

Comment: Такие, достаточно основательные вопросы, лучше не смотреть на SO. Проблема в том, что они требуют понимания основ, а его из кратких ответов на SO не получить. Поэтому лучше найти хорошую книжку по СУБД и почитать.

Comment: Я не говорил что вы кретин, не ищите в моем ответе второго смысла. Просто вам достался неправильный учебник.

Comment: В ответе нет никаких обидных слов, просто этот форум на самом деле не для этого. Чтобы описать назначение, виды PK нужно много букв. Чтобы описать использование связей между таблицами, нужно не меньше. Чтобы рассказать о нормальных формах, без которых связи строить не стоит, нужно ещё больше букв. А желающих писать книги тут не очень много :)

Comment: И небольшой коммент по ходу - редко встретишь заказ, в котором есть только один товар, часто их больше одного. Следовательно, нужно построить связь один-ко-многим между Заказом и Товаром. Для этого понадобится промежуточная таблица (так как один Товар может входить в состав разных Заказов, видим связь многие-ко-многим, которая обычно через промежуточную таблицу и разрешается)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, поймите меня и Вы. Я не ищу причины наговорить гадостей. Также хочу узнать ответы профи.  И если на первый взгляд  кажется будто я лентяй и ничерта не учу, это не так. Мне поставили задание, вероятно неправильно ибо изучать БД даже ознакомительно за полгода видим нереально.

Comment: @cVoronin, спасибо буду разбираться

Comment: Поймите и вы: вся теория реляционных БД учится за день. Только  надо найти правильный учебник. К сожалению, свой посоветовать не могу, он давно потерялся.

Comment: Проблема в том что в вашем вопросе как минимум **6** вопросов. и на каждый может быть весьма объемный ответ. попробуйте задать 6 более конкретных вопросов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей схеме реализованы 2 сущности: покупатели и товары. Связь между ними многие-ко-многим, она осуществляется с помощью смежной таблицы: заказы.

1. Внешние ключи в таблице "заказы" как раз и указывают идентификаторы в таблицах покупателей и товаров. Например, запись (1, 2, 3, 4) в таблице заказы будет показывать: 1-идентификатор заказа, 2-идентификатор пользователя, 3-идентификатор товара, 4-количество.
2. Да, эта запись означает, что поле идентификатора не может быть нулевым и увеличивается автоматически
3. Указывает кодировку и движок. Насколько я знаю, не обязательно, но желательно, особенно кодировка, потому что по умолчанию это не UTF-8
4. Да. Подробности смотреть п. 1
5. CASCADE означает, что измение записи в родительской таблице повлекут изменение в дочерней, а RESTRICT означает то, что база данных не позволит произвести изменения. То есть в вашем случае при попытке удаления товара выйдет ошибка, что связанные данные существуют в таблице заказов
6. В смежной таблице связи многие-ко-многим учитывается то, что и покупатель может заказать несколько товаров, и один товар может быть заказан несколькими покупателями. Например, записи в таблице заказов:

   (1, 1, 1, 5) - пользователь 1 заказал товар 1 в кол-ве 5 штук

   (2, 1, 2, 6) - пользователь 1 заказал товар 2 в кол-ве 6 штук

   (3, 2, 2, 8) - пользователь 2 заказал товар 2 в кол-ве 8 штук

Comment: "Заказы" тут - не связь, а отдельная сущность, имеющая свои собственные атрибуты.

Comment: *"CASCADE означает, что измение записи в родительской таблице повлекут изменение в дочерней"* - не означает. Уж точно не любое изменение.

Comment: *"Да, эта запись означает, что поле идентификатора не может быть нулевым и увеличивается автоматически"* - не означает. Наверное, вы хотели сказать "пустым", а не "нулевым"?

Comment: именно и хотел казать

Comment: @1000ISLANDS, сейчас посмотрю Ваш ответ

Comment: Если уж подходить творчески, тут всё интереснее:
- У одного Пользователя может быть несколько Заказов
- один Заказ может содержать разные Товары
- один вид Товара может входить в разные Заказы
- один пользователь может заказывать один и тот же вид Товара в разных Заказах

Comment: вроде понятно, спасибо